# getting multiple user objects using filter

Tags: python, django, django-models

Lets say,
I have a User object and I need to get a queryset with username 'foo' and 'bar'. How do i use the filter to achieve this since filter doesnot take two same kwargs.

My approach:

```
#obviously shows error
users=User.objects.filter(username='foo', username='bar')
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<fieldname>__in`:

```
users = User.objects.filter(username__in=['foo', 'bar'])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
users = User.objects.filter(username__in=['foo', 'bar'])
```

[Read the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#in)

Answer (score 0):

```
users = User.objects.filter(username__in=['foo', 'bar'])
```